# Firebase Auth transactions with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, transactions, firebase-authentication

how can make transaction in this code with flutter.

```
  FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  UserUpdateInfo userUpdateInfo = new UserUpdateInfo();
  userUpdateInfo.displayName=firstName+" "+lastName;
  await user.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo);
  await user.updateEmail(email);
```

Comment: I think that you can't. Also, you may need to call reauthenticate before call update*. methods (check. the warning at the official documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#updateEmail(java.lang.String))

Comment: @RicardoMarkiewicz i mean i want to execute this with transaction .if any error in request update profile or email i do a rollback    user.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo);
user.updateEmail(email);

Comment: I understand the question, but as far I can read in the documentation you can't do what you want.

Comment: i can't find  great solution for this problem .but i make it  successive .update one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in Authentification,Transaction and batch work with firestore no with Authentification ,If you make update successive  cause an error "this is a security sensitive operation that requires the user to have recently signed in. If this requirement isn't met, ask the user to authenticate again and later call" .you should make update One by one .